# How to find position along sine curve at given time?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I'm having trouble figuring out the following, it would be great if someone could help me out!

If Person A is moving along the curve $y=sin(x)$ at the constant speed $S$, then what is their position in the form (x, y) at time $T$?

**Edit for clarification:**

$S$ is constant speed along the [curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNM4T.png). If Person A were moving along a straight line, it's pretty clear that their x-coordinate would be just be $ST$ at time $T$. But since the arc of the sine function is longer than a straight line, this isn't the case. Thus I'm trying to find a way to express Person A's x and y coordinates at $T$, given that they're moving at a constant speed along $y=sin(x)$

Comment: Is $S=\frac{\mathsf{d}x}{\mathsf{d}t}$?

Comment: @JRN The question specifies speed *along the curve*, That would not be $dx/dt.$ It would be speed w.r.t arclength along curve.

Comment: @JRN Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand... Doesn't dx/dt refer to velocity, or did I interpret this wrong?

Comment: If the beginning of travel (time 0) was at $(0,0)$ it could be set up as an integral using the usual arlength of a graph formula. However that integral does not have a simple closed form, and without one would need to be evaluated numerically.

Comment: @coffeemath I'm not familiar with the arc length of a graph formula but I took a look at [link] (https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/arclength.aspx) this link, is this what you mean? (Assuming that the beginning of travel is at (0, 0): $L =  \int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} \,dx$, $\therefore ST =  \int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\,dx $

Comment: Speed is a scalar, velocity is a vector.  In what class was this question asked?  Was it a calculus class?  Is it a high-school class or an undergraduate class?

Comment: @MY Evaluate numerically just means to find a definite integral for which a convenient antiderivative is not available, one uses Simpsons rule or the like to approximate the value. Your L integral is just the arclength. I don't know what you mean by "ST" but in your comment it's same as L.

Comment: @coffeemath so if I understand correctly, it would work if I used numerical evaluation (e.g. through the midpoint rule or similar) to work out $L =  \int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} \,dx$? How would this link back to position at $T$ time though? I assume it would only give me the length of the curve but not an x-coordinate...

Comment: @JRN high school maths project, but it requires us to use maths beyond the curriculum

Comment: I think you need to explain your question more completely. Somehow your speed constant S needs to be in the integral. And you need to know if S is constant speed along the curve, or is it constant change in x?

Answer (score 1):

The velocity magnitude is constant. Given that the velocity magnitude is
$$v = \sqrt{\dot x ^2 + \dot y ^2 },$$ then

$$v = \sqrt{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2} = S \Rightarrow \\
\sqrt{\dot{x}^2 + \left(\dot{x} \cos(x)\right)^2} = S \Rightarrow \\\dot x = \frac{S}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}}.$$

The last equation is a separable-variables ODE which is not solvable with standard functions.

Answer (score -2):

For constant speed, you can do $x=ST$.

Thus $(x,y) = (ST,sin(ST))$.

This keeps the velocity in x-direction constant and ignores the y-direction changes.

Comment: Which is NOT constant speed!  As others have said it is the rate of change of arc length that is the constant speed S.